# Instance ELB health state has been "OutOfService"

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deploy my application on elastic-beanstalk, but I keep getting the following error :

Instance ELB health state has been `"OutOfService"` for 10 hours: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.

Can you please check the log file here -> https://ufile.io/9e94d

**main.config**

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export HOME=/root && export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /web
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: composer_options
    value: --optimize-autoloader
```

**setting.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /web
    memory_limit: 2048M
    zlib.output_compression: Off
    allow_url_fopen: On
    max_execution_time: 4000
```

[image: health check]

Comment: I have tried to deploy a new application and it works fine, but with my symfony2 application it doesn't  ....any help please.

Comment: The log file is gone.